# Two Doubly list for C

Tags: c, struct, casting

I am writing a code using Doubly Linked List for C language. I am trying to create two doubly linked list sorted.

The objective is having two list, 'List A' and 'List B'. I need to insert list B into A in a orderly sort.

```
    if( head2 != NULL)
{
    struct ListNode *newnode;
    //struct ListNode2 *newnode2;

    currentnode = tail;
    int currentint = currentnode->list1;
    printf("( %d )", currentint);

    currentnode2 = tail2;
    int currentint2 = currentnode2->list2;
    printf("( %d )", currentint2);

    newnode = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));

    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        if (currentint2 < currentint)
        {
            newnode->list1 = currentint2;
            addnode(newnode);
            currentnode2 = currentnode2->previous2;
            currentint2 = currentnode2->list2;
            printf("( %d )", currentint2);

        }
        else
        {
            currentnode = currentnode->previous;
            currentint = currentnode->list1;
            printf("( %d )", currentint);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to insert 'List B' into 'List A' after certain or unknown amount, the program breaks down. (Debugging is another story) 
Any help is appreciated. Note: Just Starting C but already know Java.

Comment: Run it in the debugger who will tell you **where** the crash occurs, which will give you a hint **why** the programs crashes.

Comment: It looks like you are missing several pieces of the puzzle to insert ListB into ListA in sort order. You will first iterate ListA until you find the largest node in ListA that is less than the first node in ListB (say nodeA). You then insert the first node of ListB (nodeB) after nodeA (e.g.  `tmp=nodeA->next;` `nodeA->next = nodeB;`), then iterate ListB comparing `tmp` to find the new nodeB and insert `tmp` in ListB where needed (e.g. `tmpB=nodeB->next;` `nodeB->next=tmp;`) and then *repeat* - iterating ListA to find out where `tmpB` fits). I don't see that anywhere in your code?

Comment: I didn't add my sorting code to the question since it wasn't my problem. I wanted was just adding ListB into listA.

Comment: Debugger is whole another story. I will get back to this question once I figured out why eclipse doesn't have GDB --version.

Comment: Well, I got it working now. Thank you for your help.